# Получить расположение только что снятого фото в Android 7.0

Tags: java, android

После съёмки фото невозможно получить его расположение из `Intent`. Хотя съёмка проходит успешно.
Работаю с системным приложением камеры Android 7.0. Разрешение `CAMERA` и `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` предоставляются.

Формирую `Intent` так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Запускаю камеру.

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ID_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Фото снимается и после получаю его расположение так:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_ID_IMAGE_CAPTURE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
            OrderFile orderFile = new OrderFile();
            File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(this, data.getData())); // Здесь вылетает ошибка.
```

Самое интересное, в Android 4.4 всё нормально работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) использования `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, приложение камеры не обязано возвращать URI сделанного снимка, это не задокументировано. В `data.getExtras("data")` возвращается уменьшенная превьюшка. Если хотите получить путь к сделанному снимку, необходимо в `EXTRA_OUTPUT` передать путь к файлу, куда приложение камеры должно сохранить снимок. При этом, обязанность сохранения URI, который передается в `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, если планируется в дальнейшем использовать в коде, лежит на разработчике - в `onActivityResult` оно не возвращается.

Comment: Не помогло.`android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference`.

Comment: При использовании `EXTRA_OUTPUT` вы сами должны сохранить тот URI, который передали. Обратно оно не возвращается в `onActivityResult`